# Code To a custom tab in my account customer section in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I need a code to add a custom tab in the magento 2.1 customer account .
Please provide complete code for that

thanks

Answer (score 6):

All you need is a **customer_account.xml** in the frontend layout of your module and add the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-my-customlink">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your_custom_url_path</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link</argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Find more details in that [post](https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/add-customer-sign-out-link-in-my-account-navigation-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can create **customer_account.xml** under below file path

> Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout

or add code if it exits.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="custom-customer-account-tab">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">custom_url(test/save/)</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"> Custom name</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```